# How can I make video's shrink to fit in HTML

Tags: html, css, video

This is my code:

```
    <div class="sameline">

        <video width="800" height="315" controls>
            <source src="../videosrecords/Half Brothers.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
```

For some reason, the controls end up looking really weird. Like this:
[image]
I'm creating a movie-sharing website so all containers should be in the same size. How can I set it up so that the movie perfectly fits the video area?
The website can be located at: https://jokerfilms.000webhostapp.com/video/HalfBrothers

Comment: On my pc its looks ok! what is the problem?

Comment: I have highlighted the issue [here](https://imgur.com/a/VUuiOFd). The extra space border is really annoying and is ruining the design. I'd like the video to fit the whole border the way it does for [this](https://jokerfilms.000webhostapp.com/video/WonderWoman) video.

Comment: your half brother video also looks good on my pc Its showing the way you are showing error its looking normal on my pc

Comment: try restarting some time it happens when we for hours!

Comment: what browser do u use and on what resolution? just checking

Comment: I use chrome and I have the default settings on